# New reputation area. Recent changes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

In the old reputation area when you got any recent rep the line was highlighted.

In the new version all i see is the text bolded (and nothing highlighted) and it is hard to tell the difference between the two:

#### Can you find the new one here?

[image: can you find it?]

#### Well its here:

[image]

---

Now I have noticed it is not even telling me how much rep I have earned recently:[image]

---

### It seems

That this was fixed on meta :-)

Still waiting on SO.

Comment: According to Firebug, the other entries are bold, too, so it's _even_ less differentiated than you think.

Comment: I noticed recently that all their stuff started running from a new CDN, I think [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net). Most of the notifiers and such didn't work until I allowed that domain. I know the orange-ish highlights don't work without the JavaScript.

Comment: @animuson - That's been around since 2009 - Check [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/) for details.  I'm pretty sure that this is unrelated to the CDN, rather, it's a function of the new user page and has been reported as [an answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112799) the [feature announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112151), in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113333) (which has a bounty and some 40 votes), and [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113446), closed as a dupe of the former.

Comment: @KevinVermeer lol http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113333 is a dupe of this question :-P

Comment: @AMan - You're right, this one is older!  Sorry for the confusion, but it does seem to be resolved in any case.  Perhaps the extra 100 points from having two separate bounties and the duplicate votes on the questions were extra-motivating to Geoff?

Comment: @KevinVermeer hehe idk, they should really close the other and merge :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been deployed to production - alerts are now active.