# New profile format: How do we get the "alerts" back?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, profile-page

I noticed that the format of the user page changed today. In the old format, next to the "reputation" and "response" headers there would be a number (highlighted in red) telling you the number of new entries, so it was easy to notice that somebody had addressed a comment to you. The new format does not include this and I don't see anything else that provides that information visibly.

Can we get some alert mechanism like we had?

Comment: Maybe they plan to bring the Envelope back! ;) Seriously now - good point, would like to have this mechanism in place as well. From what I see they either forgot or maybe still planning something.

Comment: I hope it comes back because I really miss those blue icons next to the tabs. Like when I got reputation it would show a little blue icon next to it. (in Stack Overflow) I like the new profile but I do miss those little alerts.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112799/84237)?

Comment: @Arjan, yeah, looks like.  My question was migrated here from another meta site so I'm not familiar with the norms here -- should feature requests be in stand-alone posts like where this came from, or collected together in that one post as seems to be happening here?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Typically, you would make a stand-alone post like this. In this case, they created a specific question to solicit input while it was being tested here on meta.SO. Now that it's been deployed across the network, they're both probably acceptable.

Comment: (@Monica, I was just adding some cross-references. I guess I'd better have written "See also". No sweat!)

Comment: Yes, all of a sudden, stackoverflow became a lot less useful to me and I became a lot less responsive to those questions I'm participating in.  Why did they remove such valuable functionality.

Comment: Duplicate of: [New reputation area. Recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112256/new-reputation-area-recent-changes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have deployed notifications for the new user page redesign.  Let us know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Geoff it seems this was only done on meta, correct? (re: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112256/new-reputation-area-recent-changes)

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama we just pushed it out to the entire network

Comment: @GeoffDalgas cool ^_^ can you mark my Q as [meta-tag:status-completed] (which this one is a **dupe** of).

Comment: Excellent Geoff. The indicators were a pleasant surprise when I logged in today. :)

Comment: @Geoff Could I know how do you know which of them ARE notified and which are not? Is there a special field "notified" in votes table (assuming you're getting reputation changes based on votes table)?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: The indicators don't seem to be working at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com). I just got an upvote on a question there... but no indicator.

Answer (score 17):

I’m in total agreement — though not in a position to do anything about it but complain.

As an active user on Stack Overflow, I found the little blue number indicating changes in responses, reputation, etc. to be the single most important piece of information on my profile page. I could look at my profile throughout the day and see if anyone responded to my comments or if an answer was accepted.

In short, it enables us to be responsive over a number of posts without having to monitor each post manually. I think it’s an important feature that needs to be reimplemented.

### Update

Nick Carver commented on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112799/168341):

> This was a styling issue more than anything else, we're now
>   constrained space-wise horizontally with the tabs. The indicators are
>   being worked on right now, I'm converting mobile to use the new code
>   and Dalgas is working on indicators, you should see them return soon.

At least we now know the indicators are coming back. This is good news.