# Option to have the old profile information display?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New profile format: How do we get the “alerts” back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113333/new-profile-format-how-do-we-get-the-alerts-back)

Should we be able to select the old formatting instead of the "new look" for our profile information?

EDIT:

I miss how whenever you gained/lost reputation, the little tab on the top right would say a number of how much reputation change there was, and you could click on it for more information. Now all it does is display the timeline.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to maintain two different profile displays. If you have problems with the new one, why don't you suggest how it can be improved instead?

Answer (score 6):

No. Having the look change depending on the profile you're looking at would be massively confusing; it needs to be consistent from person to person. If there's a problem with it you can [try to get it changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live), but having two totally different pages isn't a good idea. This is the same thing Facebook goes through every time they push a major change -- everybody flips out, people join "1 million users demanding old Facebook" groups, and a week later they've forgotten that the old look ever existed

Comment: I look at my own profile on different SE sites way more often than I look at different users on the same one.  Since only some sites are using the new profile I already see inconsistent pages.  (But I don't want an option; I want them to fix it.  I am the person who asked the question this was linked to.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well yes, that's annoying but temporary; eventually all the sites will have the new profile view. A setting that lets people make them inconsistent permanently would be bad

Comment: Oh, drat -- I thought individual sites were being allowed to take this or not, and had hopes that at least some of mine would keep the more-usable format.

Comment: The link in the answer is not working

Comment: @user31782 This is ancient, it's talking about an older profile rewrite, and that link points to a question that was deleted after that rewrite went live. The latest rewrite was covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Can I make the profile page look like how it was a year ago? E.g. Phys.SE still has old profile view http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1822/fidelio.

Comment: @user31782 No, it's just [not live on all sites yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), but it will be. There's no way to go back