# What happened to "responses"?

Tags: support, profile-page, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New profile format: How do we get the “alerts” back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113333/new-profile-format-how-do-we-get-the-alerts-back)

You click on your name and it doesn't go to "responses" anymore.  And there's no count of un-viewed responses on the tabs to clue you in to look there.  Seems like a major step backwards.

Comment: This sucks, when will there be a fix?

Answer (score 6):

I assume they removed the blue count bubbles because there's no room for them. On my view, there's only about 30 spare pixels to the left of all the tabs that they could add counts next to the titles, and one count for any title would probably take up all that space. So if you had multiple tabs with unchecked information (blue counts), it would overflow past the bounds of the menu.

However, I do find it a tad irritating that it there's *no* notification of updates under the tabs. Could we at least get the tab text to turn blue (or maybe orange to match the colors) when there are unchecked updates under any particular tab?

Answer (score 4):

Under the new layout, responses appears as one of the many tabs, third from right in my view. <del>As far as I can tell, it continues to clue you in with the blue count of unviewed.</del>

**EDIT:**

Wait, you're right about blue count not appearing any more. And it's missing for new reputation also. Looks like a bug?