# New user page - missing functionality

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New reputation area. Recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112256/new-reputation-area-recent-changes)
>   [New profile format: How do we get the “alerts” back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113333/new-profile-format-how-do-we-get-the-alerts-back)

There are a couple of features that the old user page had that I miss:

- When there were changes to favorites, the tab got highlighted. This is no longer the case.
- When reputation changed between visits (when sorting by time), the changed had a highlight - this is no longer my case.

Bring back the highlights!

Comment: Partial dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113333/new-profile-format-how-do-we-get-the-alerts-back

Comment: +1 for the reputation highlight. Important feature that has gone missing.

Comment: +1. I'm missing this too as well as the highlight (and count) on the responses tab.