# Why weren't these duplicates merged?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

Original Question: [New reputation area. Recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112256/155556)

I had flagged **two** other questions as duplicates and they **were** marked helpful:

1. [New profile format: How do we get the "alerts" back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113333/155556)
2. [New user page - missing functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113696/155556)

Can we merge these three questions so we don't have three of the same thing floating around?

There might be more duplicates, but these are the ones that I have found so far that have been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by the mods.

Answer (score 1):

If you already flagged it and the flags were dismissed (flags are pretty much always dismissed helpful), a mod has already reviewed it, so there isn't really a reason for a meta post unless you're asking "why weren't they merged?". They probably weren't merged because one of the posts has no answers, so merging wouldn't do anything, and the other has a duplicate answer. Merging is useful if the exact same question is asked twice and two good but different answers are posted

Comment: I updated the question to my OP.

Comment: This is correct: Merging two questions is not done on any questions that are marked as duplicated.

Comment: @kiamlaluno but when they have a great following they should be **at least** marked as duplicates publicly which they are **not**....

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama Of course, but that's up to 3k users, not mods

Comment: @MichaelMrozek mods can mark it duplicate without any help from the users.

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama Yes, but users can mark it duplicate without any help from the mods. In theory users are supposed to take care of what they can, and get mods to [intervene when necessary](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama In this case, it is up to the developers, and they preferred to simply mark as [meta-tag:status-completed] the different questions. For them it has the same effect, as they don't watch anymore questions tagged as [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @kiamlaluno haha how do you know what the mods watch and do not watch?

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama I said, "developers." For them, having three questions tagged [meta-tag:status-complete], or having just one question tagged with that tag doesn't make any difference; in any case, they know they have already taken care of what reported, and they will not keep watching those questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ooook....